# Suddenly I can't print to my OfficeJet Pro 8500A Plus

Tags: network-printer

I've got an HP OfficeJet Pro 8500A Plus all-in-one printer/scanner.  It's setup to use wireless connectivity to my home network.  Every PC and laptop can, and has, printed to it fine, until Saturday.  Then suddenly nothing and print to it.  On every PC and laptop if we submit anything to the printer it goes into that PC/laptop's queue, and there it sits, until I delete it from the queue.  I've run a test print job, and that works fine.  I downloaded the HP Print and Scan Doctor 2.0 app, ran it and as far as it is concerned everything fine.  The only way anything can print anything to the printer is to reboot the machine that has submitted something to the printer, which frankly is very inconvenient.

What would cause my OfficeJet Pro 8500A to stop printing all print jobs?

Answer (score 0):

> I've run a test print job

I'll assume that you mean you did a test print on the printer itself, rather than from a PC.

If my guess is correct, there may be printjob stuck in the queue on the serving PC. To check, go to that PC and double-click the printer. Delete any jobs that show up, and see if that fixes the problem.

BTW, as the printer has wireless connection, for a home network it's probably better to set every PC up like the server (i.e. using wireless direct to the printer). That way you don't rely on the server being alive for printing.

Comment: You are correct, I did mean a print self test, which worked.

I hadn't thought of what you suggested, so I asked everyone in my family if any of them had submitted any print jobs in the last couple of days.  3 had.  I checked on all three computers and none of them had anything in their queues.

No machine is setup as a print server.  Each machine is setup to manage it's own queue to the OfficeJet.